# Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1) null ^

Tags: flutter, dart

**is there a solution to this problem??**
*

> **[Link Full Code -> click here](https://pickle-fold-909.notion.site/Error-Flutter-e1a04069ef664924a1477fa182eb7274)**

- 

Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)
null
^

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKqCO.png)

```
  child: Column(
            children: [
              ...(question[questionIndex]['answer']as List<Map<String,Object>>).map((value){
                return Answer(()=> answerQuestion(int.parse(value['Score'].toString()))! ,value['text'].toString());
              }).toList() ,



            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `FormatException` gets thrown when `int.parse` tries to parse a String that does not contain numbers only.
In your case, `value['Score']` is `null`, which is definitely not a number.

So to fix your error you need to either

- Check `value['Score']` for `null` and, if it is null, not try to parse it
- Make sure that it contains a valid, parseable number (Maybe you meant the lowercase `value['score']`?)

Comment: Thank you, it has been resolved